# How to run Vue.js app with json-server backend simultaneously on cyclic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend, backend

I'm trying to deploy my Vue.js application on Cyclic, and I'm facing issues with running the frontend and backend scripts concurrently. The frontend is built with Vue.js, and I'm using json-server as a fake REST API for the backend. The problem is that I need to run both the frontend (dev script) and the backend (json-server) simultaneously for the application to work correctly.

Here's my current package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "backend": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.3",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I'm using the dev script to run the Vue.js frontend, and the backend script to run the json-server backend. Locally, I can run these two scripts concurrently using the concurrently package with the command npm run dev and npm run backend. However, when deploying the application on Cyclic, I'm unsure how to achieve the same behavior.

Additionally, I'm not sure how to run the backend on Cyclic since it's using the port number 5000. How can I deploy my Vue.js application on Cyclic, run both the frontend and backend scripts simultaneously, and ensure that the backend is accessible on port 5000? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a process manager like PM2 to run frontend and backend scripts simultaneously on Cyclic.

First of all, you can install PM2 on your cyclic server.

Now you can change the package.json that works with PM2.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production",
  "stop": "pm2 stop ecosystem.config.js",
  "restart": "pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js",
  "backend": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000",
  "dev": "vite"
},
```

You will also need to add an environment configuration file to make both backend and front end scripts work simultaneously.We can use seperate ports to run the scripts seperately.

After that we can simply start the process using PM2.
Note - You might need to configure the server's firewall and hostname configuration to access the backend or front end.